# In My app i'm using login with Facebook SDK and its work on AVD but didn't work on real device?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-login

This is my code which is I'm trying now it's working on Avd but when i'm use the real android device debug option they didn't not enter the **onActivityResult** function help me?

```
package com.example.nhp04.gqfood;
import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;



public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements Animation.AnimationListener {

private String info = "";
private LoginButton loginButton;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private AccessTokenTracker tracker;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);



loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            info = ("User ID: " + 

    loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId() + "\n" + "Auth Token: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    info = ("Login attempt canceled.");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                    info = ("Login attempt failed.");
                }
            });
            System.out.println(info);
            tracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken) {

            }
        };
        tracker.startTracking();
    }
    }
```

this function for checking login

```
public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        return accessToken != null;
    }
```

this on Resume and on Stop methods

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (isLoggedIn()){
            Intent home = new Intent(this, home.class);
            startActivity(home);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        tracker.stopTracking();
        finish();
    }
```

And this is my **onActivityResult** function when i debug the code on real device this function didn't execute but it's work on AVD..

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Intent home = new Intent(this, home.class);
            startActivity(home);
        } else {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working properly the error is i was using the `debugger key store` in Facebook sdk app now i'm using the `RELEASE_KEYSTORE` and it's working good.

Answer (score 0):

when you extend & @Override onActivityResult, I guess you need to call super.onActivityResult(...) method?

Comment: I don't have facebook sdk, so cannot test. check if this one helps. http://www.it1352.com/148179.html (terminal: keytool -exportcert -alias androireleasekey -keystore PATH_TO_THE_RELEASE_KEYSTORE | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64)